# How to compute sin(a * t) from sin(a) and cos(a)

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

As the title says, I have `sin(a)` and `cos(a)` and I would like to compute `sin(a * t)` and `cos(a * t)`, where `t` is in the closed interval `[0, 1]`.

Is this possible?

EDIT: The comments/answers made me realise I have another restriction I didn't specify in my original question: `a` is in the closed interval `[0, 2*pi]`

Comment: If you have $\sin a$ but not $a$ itself, then you don't know whether you have $\sin a$ or $\sin(a+2\pi)$, and they will give different values of $\sin at$.

Comment: If you have $\sin a$ and $\cos a$ and $a\in[0,2\pi)$, then you can calculate $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible without added restrictions.

For example, if $a = \frac{\pi}{6}$, then the function $f(t)=\sin(at)$ will be a strictly increasing function from $0$ to $\frac12$:

[Plot of the function when $a=\frac\pi6$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sin(pi%2F6%20*%20t)%20for%20t%20in%20%5B0,1%5D)

while if if $a=2\pi + \frac\pi6$, the function will take both negative and positive values and will not be strictly increasing.

[Plot of the function when $a=2\pi + \frac\pi6$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sin((2%5Cpi%20%2B%20pi%2F6)%20*%20t)%20for%20t%20in%20%5B0,1%5D)

However, $\sin a$ and $\cos a$ will be the same in both cases.

---

Perhaps even more obvious case comes if you set $a=0$ (in which case, the function $\sin(at)=\sin(0\cdot t) = 0$ is constant) or $a=2\pi$ (in which case, the function is exactly one period of $\sin$, shrunk to $[0,1]$.

---

However, if you restrict $a$ to $[0,2\pi)$, then the values of $\sin a$, $\cos a$ precisely determine what $a$ is, and you can calculate $a$ as being one of $\arcsin (a), 2\pi + \arcsin (a), \pi - \arcsin(a)$ (depending on the sign of $\cos (a)$). After you calculate $a$, it should be easy to see what $\sin(at)$ is.